# ASP and TypeScript issue: input value changed with jQuery not caught using binding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, typescript

In my viewmodel I have the attribute Trefwoord:

public trefwoord: KnockoutObservable; in a class in .ts file
    "Trefwoord": this.trefwoord(),

The binding on the cshtml file is the following:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="trefwoord" data-bind="text: trefwoord" /> 
</div>
```

When I change the value of the textbox with the keyboard and hit the search button (POST page)
and set a breakpoint the value of Trefwoord is inside the viewmodel parameter.

But when I do the changing with jQuery: `$("#trefwoord").val('value');`
Then the value set by jQuery is not being send or even noticed.

Could someone please help me out

Comment: what kind of control $("#trefwoord") is ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually update items via the observable - this causes the UI to update automatically (this is what I'm using Knockout for). For example...

```
myModel.trefwoord('value');
```

Given that `this.trefwoord` is a KnockoutObservable...

```
this.trefwoord('value');
```

And the `input` changes automatically.